# Next.js npm run build then npm start yielding high CPU usage

Tags: next.js

I recently been learning Next.js and just finished a rough draft of a site. So far, I have done `npm run build` and `npm start`. However, when I opened localhost:3000 just to test the rough draft. My cpu usage went through the roof. There is no known bug in my code as far as I know of, since everything works fine. However, it makes me wonder if I perhaps built my app in a not optimized "Next.js" way or I should just be running `npm run dev` only, even though the production site may output differing results than the development phase...

Comment: Does the CPU spike happens when compiling only or do they happen during runtime?

Comment: It happens during runtime, not when it's compiling!